# Residuals in linear regression

Tags: regression

Suppose I have a linear regression model 
$$
\mathbf y = \mathbf X \mathbf b + \boldsymbol{\varepsilon},\,\boldsymbol{\varepsilon}\sim \mathcal N(\mathbf 0, \sigma ^2\mathbf I) 
$$
and use ML approach in order to estimate $\mathbf b$, that is:
$$
\hat{\mathbf b}_{\mathrm {ML}} = (\mathbf X ^\top \mathbf X)^{-1}\mathbf X^\top \mathbf y
$$
Consider residuals:
$$
\mathbf r = \mathbf y - \mathbf X\hat{\mathbf b}_{\mathrm {ML}} = (\mathbf I - \mathbf X(\mathbf X ^\top \mathbf X)^{-1}\mathbf X^\top) \mathbf y \sim \mathcal N(\mathbf 0, \sigma ^2(\mathbf I - \mathbf P)^2),
$$
where $\mathbf P = \mathbf X(\mathbf X ^\top \mathbf X)^{-1}\mathbf X^\top$.

How can I test normality of $\mathbf r$ using QQ- or PP-plots?

And another question: what is an unbiased estimate for $\sigma$ (since ML approach leads to biased estimate for $\sigma ^2$ as well as $\sigma$)?

Comment: As in one of the recent posts, also here I think it would be more common to use either $\hat \beta$ or $\text{b}$ in place of $\hat{\text{b}}$.

Comment: I use C. Bishop's notation (except $\mathbf b$, while Bishop uses $\mathbf w$) for which $\beta$ stands for precision, i.e. inverse variance. However, thanks for advice, I will keep it in mind.

Comment: How are you going to calculate $(I-P)^{-1}$?

Comment: Oops, I have missed the fact that $\mathbf P$ is a projector, that is its inverse does not exist. Therefore, how can I test normality of $\mathbf r$ using QQ-plot?

Answer (score 1):

The components are independent, because the covariance of any two components is zero. You can see some more information about that [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normally_distributed_and_uncorrelated_does_not_imply_independent). I.e. having a diagonal covariance matrix implies that the covariance is zero, thus the individual components are independent.

Your second question is a bit more difficult. You can find an answer [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_least_squares#Assuming_normality), but explaining the details may require a bit longer answer.

Also when you say in the beginning that this is an ML approach, I do not completely agree. This is well established theory that is quite a lot older than ML, so I would rather refer to it as OLS, linear regression or linear model in general.